# select inputs elements having attribute "name" value ending in "someValue"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select all inputs elements having the attribute "name" value ending in "[date]", like:

```
<input name="[blabla][hello][date]">
```

This is what I tried, but doesn't work:

```
$('input[name=*\[date\]]');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **Attribute Ends With Selector `[name$=”value”]`**, this way:

```
$('input[name$="[date]"]');
```

Or if one of the attribute should have `[date]`:

```
$('input[name*="[date]"]');
```

You can find more in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

> #### Attribute Ends With Selector [name$=”value”]
>
> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.
>
> ```
> jQuery( "[attribute$='value']" )
> ```